# in html adding a logo and a login form in site's header

Tags: html, forms, authentication, header

I was trying to create a page in html looking like facebook. A page where in header it will be my logotype and next to it two boxes with a button in order to allow users to login. Under that it will be a main page with a registration form for new users that need to register.

Any ideas where I can found such code examples? Any tutoriasl or links?

Thanks guys

Comment: Too generic of a question imho.  Hard to say there's an answer to this question.

Comment: view the source of the page you want to emulate.  Learn from it.  Also, what are you planning to use for your backend?

Comment: Why not install wordpress and get a register frontpage plugin. Easy as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link of tutorials that can help you http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp